# Twitter BootStrap Typeahead onselect fire ajax

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In Twitter BootStrap ajax query, When one of the suggestion is selected, a new ajax query is not sent.
In my case, i want to get more suggestions by firing a new ajax query, once the user selects a suggestion.
How to achieve this?

Comment: [Consider this fork of Typeahead and allows for the onSelect() event](https://gist.github.com/Yavari/1891669)

Comment: Default bootstrap also has onselect event right? In the onselect event i need to notify that the data is changed. How to notify that the data is changed?